# jQuery insert ul between elements

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have the following structure:

```
 <ul>
   <li id="first">Fist Item</li>
   <li id="second">Second Item</li>
   <li id="third">Third Item</li>
   ..................
  </ul>
```

I need to insert an ul element around the second item that looks like this:

```
 <ul>
   <li id="first">Fist Item</li>
   <ul id="active">
     <li id="second">Second Item</li>
   </ul> 
   <li id="third">Third Item</li>
   ..................
  </ul>
```

Comment: your html becomes invalid `ul` should have `li` as children

Comment: Probably you should add the class active to the `second` element instead of wrapping it

Comment: I have change the question replaced the div with an ul element because this was what i need in the first place, the div was for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

```
$("#second").wrap("<div id='active'></div>");
```

---

P.S - Like other users have already written on comments, you should probably work with classes instead of adding a wrapping element. That way, the following code:

```
$("#second").addClass("active");
```

Will result in the following DOM:

```
<ul>
    <li id="first">Fist Item</li>
    <li id="second" class="active">Second Item</li>
    <li id="third">Third Item</li>
</ul>
```